# Show intro image in Category List

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, component, joomla-3.4, templates

I added this line in my custom template to display the image:

```
<?php echo $article->images; ?>
```

And I got this as a result:

```
{"image_intro":"images\/articles\/liang2.jpg","float_intro":""}
```

So, I tried to display the image using this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $images->image_intro; ?>" >
```

The output is this:
`<img src="">` instead of `<img src="images/articles/liang2.jpg">`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do and where you are doing it?

Answer (score 2):

The image is part of a JSON encoded string, which you saw by echoing `$article->images;`.

Therefore, before trying to display the image, you'll need to decode the string first, like so:

```
$images = json_decode($article->images);
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you included some explanations.

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. You are just missing the step of decoding the `$article->images` json string.

Like "A. Snake" correctly said, you have to convert the JSON string into an object by which you can access each key and value.

[PHP's manual page for the json_decode() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

So this will work:

```
$images = json_decode($article->images);
echo $images->image_intro
```

Or you can perform it in a single line within your tag like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo json_decode($article->images)->image_intro; ?>" >
```

To write a variable declaration using the decoded the JSON string, use the following syntax:

```
$value = $JSON_object->key
```

See the php manual for more specifications and examples.